# Joomla Template - Helix framework - error.php

Tags: php, templates, joomla, helix

I have a Joomla Template that uses the Helix framework (Two | Responsive & Multipurpose Template ). The Template has an error.php and all errors are forwarded to a special error page. Now I want to realize, that all 401 errror are forwarded to the login page. 
I used this code:

```
$error   = $this->error->getCode();
// redirect 401 messages to login
if ($error == '401') {
    header('Location: index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
    exit;
}
```

But Joomla ignores my changes.
Do I have to edit another file?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to trap a 404 error and provide a custom message.

```
<?php  if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') { ?>
    header('Location: index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
    exit;
<?php } ?>
```